# UIButton Programmatically based on device

Tags: ios4, xcode4, uibutton, ipad

I have created a UIButton programmatically that is inserted on either a iPhone or iPad only application. Is it possible to do it for a universal app (i.e....change the size of the button and location to fit the device UI)?

```
//insert button for inbox///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

appButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];

        [appButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"18-envelope.png"]       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        appButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        appButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        appButton.frame = CGRectMake(290.0, 25.0, 24.0, 24.0);
        [appButton addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(showAppInbox)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [self.window addSubview:appButton];


//END/////////////////////////////////



//Call method to show inbox
-(void) showAppInbox
{
[[AppInboxManager sharedManager] show];
}
```

//new code
//BEGIN insert button for INBOX///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])

    {


    appButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 25, 24, 16);



   }

    else

    {

    appButton.frame = CGRectMake(700, 25, 24, 16);


    }

    appButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];

    [appButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"envelope_white.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    appButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    appButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    [appButton addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(showAppInbox)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: place     appButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
before the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make the following:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString: @"iPhone"]){


      appButton.frame=XXXX;

}else{

      appButton.frame=YYYY;

}
```

More Information in:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: Thanks Saimonx...I do have one error..."Expected "]" on the if statement line

Comment: You were missing a ":" after isEqualToString. Now, for some reason on my iPhone the button is gone but it is where I specified it on the iPad

Comment: sorry for the ":", show me the code that you are using, please.

Comment: It looks like it is skipping straight to the else statement.

Comment: place a NSLog(@"Model: %s",[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]); For the iPhone, maybe it is "iPhone OS", or something like that instead "iPhone"

Comment: see above addition I just made

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

@Saimonx thanks for pushing me in the right direction. I found the answer and it was done using the following:

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
//put your code here
}

else

{
//put your code here
}
```